# CSRF Token missing when trying to get GET request from DVWA

Tags: brute-force, csrf-token

I'm currently trying to do Brute Force Attack on my DVWA virtual machine. Both LOW and MEDIUM works perfectly fine with BurpSuite. However when I'm trying level HIGH - as I read in documentation I expect to find additional info about user token. But it's not there, I checked everything so many times and I don't know where the problem is.

This is how it looks:
[There is login and password but token is missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BZRD.png)

Does any of you know what could be a problem??